# Swift 3D Touch BSMachError

Tags: swift, debugging

I am trying to 'preview' a view controller through 3D touch. The code, as it is, does work, however the exiting preview animation is jittery and the following error pops up on the terminal.

```
2019-07-16 11:22:51.049757+0100 VisualisationsUIKit[439:29734] [Common] _BSMachError: port d90f; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
```

Some googling showed me that this error often goes away if you remove all breakpoints or change the 'Localization native development region' in info.plist but neither helped.

The code for the 'peak & pop' is below:

```
//PEAK & POP
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }
        let selectedVis = filteredVisualisations[indexPath.row]
        //guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else { return nil}

        let identifier = "GIFViewController"
        guard let GIFVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? GIFViewController else { return nil}

        GIFVC.selection = selectedVis

        GIFVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 190)

        return GIFVC
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {

        let selectedVis = (viewControllerToCommit as! GIFViewController).selection

        let identifier = "DetailViewController"

        //force unwrap?
        let detailVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! DetailViewController

        detailVC.selectedVis = selectedVis

        self.show(detailVC, sender: self)
    }

}



//PREVIEW VIEW CONTROLLER

import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class GIFViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var GIFView: UIImageView!

    var selection = visualisations[0]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //GIFView.loadGif(name: selection.name + "_gif")

        GIFView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: selection.gifURL))

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool = true) {
        SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()
    }
    deinit {
        print("DEALLOCATED GIFViewController class")
    }

}
```